# npm install stuck at extract: zone.js

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, npm, single-page-application

I am not an expert on JS so this problem might have an easy solution. I am trying out .Net Core Angular SPA template. When I try to run `npm install` command, it gets stuck on `extract:zone.js` step. Here is the command output.

```
D:\Projects\UI>cd ClientApp

D:\Projects\UI\ClientApp>npm install
[       ...........] / extract:zone.js: verb lock using C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-f4d27da8ef6cdab8.lock for D:\Projects\UI\ClientApp\node_modules\.staging
```

I tried reinstalling node and npm, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Here is my node and npm version.

```
D:\Projects\UI\ClientApp>npm version
{ AngularMaterial: '0.0.0',
  npm: '6.4.1',
  ares: '1.14.0',
  cldr: '33.1',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '62.1',
  modules: '64',
  napi: '3',
  nghttp2: '1.34.0',
  node: '10.12.0',
  openssl: '1.1.0i',
  tz: '2018e',
  unicode: '11.0',
  uv: '1.23.2',
  v8: '6.8.275.32-node.35',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

I haven't added or removed anything from the default .net core Angular SPA template. Thanks for help.

**More details**
Here are the commands that I have already tried.

```
D:\Projects\UI\ClientApp>npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

D:\Projects\UI\ClientApp>npm install --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Users\\rahul\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@6.4.1
npm info using node@v10.12.0
npm verb npm-session 4b2214d86e04af5b
npm info lifecycle AngularMaterial@0.0.0~preinstall: AngularMaterial@0.0.0
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 12ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 494ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 678ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 1408ms
npm timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 352ms
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-f4d27da8ef6cdab8.lock for D:\Projects\NamitUI\ClientApp\node_modules\.staging
npm timing audit compress Completed in 233ms
npm info audit Submitting payload of 66762bytes
npm timing audit submit Completed in 1900ms
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 1903ms
npm timing audit body Completed in 4ms
[       ...........] / extract:zone.js: timing audit body Completed in 4ms
```

Running the command with -ddd flag generates similar output with the last few steps looking like this. Here is the pastebin for complete log: https://pastebin.com/gnvn1wHe

```
npm sill tarball trying async-each@1.0.1 by hash: sha1-GdOGodntxufByF04iu28xW0zYC0=
npm sill tarball trying async-foreach@0.1.3 by hash: sha1-NhIfhFwFeBct5Bmpfb6x0W7DRUI=
npm timing audit submit Completed in 2163ms
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 2014ms
npm timing audit body Completed in 4ms
[       ...........] / extract:zone.js: timing audit body Completed in 4ms
```

Comment: Run npm with -ddd flag, then you will find out which URL it tries to fetch and gets stuck. Either there is a network issue or there is a dependency which is blocking the extraction process.

Comment: looks still the same. I have updated the question with output of the command.

Comment: I just waited for sometime, and it worked.

Answer (score 17):

Little late to answer, I hope will help someone else.

Delete `package-lock.json` and remove node modules folder. Try again with `npm cache clean --force` (you might get a warning because this cleaning process is handled by `npm` itself.) and then `npm install --save`

I was facing the same problem. It worked for me.

Comment: When calling npm I get a black screen that goes away after one second. I am behind a corporate firewall and would like to call `npm install` for a `reveal.js` app.

Comment: Can confirm. Deleting node modules did the trick for me after downgrading npm from v7 to v6

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and i fixed it by changing the registry from

```
http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

to

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

To change the link you can use

```
npm config set registry <link>
```

or you can also open the npm's configuration file with

```
notepad ~/.npmrc
```

and change the registry line with the right link.

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I think the issue come from the proxy of my company I added to npm. It requires to use https

Answer (score 1):

One time I got stuck because the registry(not npmjs.org) was inaccessible unless i am on our organization's VPN. Issue resolved after connecting.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this was my issue.
You can check with `npm config get registry` to see if yours is private.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `npm install` and I upgraded both node and npm and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this for an old repo using node 16.10~. I tried 14,12,10, they were all even more broken during install. Eventually tried 16.22, and that suddenly worked.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Random note: when npm seems to be stuck, it might be stuck on a different thing than it shows. On Linux, do a `ps axf | grep npm -C3` to show what npm and its subprocesses are up to. For example, if you see there's some `git ls-remote` child process staying around for long, likely it is the one thing stuck. Investigate why. (Other more heavy-weight option is to `strace` the process to see what it is doing, but likey you won't need this).